# how to identify shape of tensor while using batch_size in keras (initial_value must have a shape specified)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, batchsize

I have a `custom layer`, in one line of this custome layer I do like this:

```
out = tf.Variable(tf.zeros(shape=tf.shape(tf_a1), dtype=tf.float32))
```

When I run code, I received this error:

> ValueError: initial_value must have a shape specified:
>   Tensor("lambda_1/zeros_2:0", shape=(?, 20), dtype=float32)

I searched and find out that I can use `validate_shape=False`

So I change the code to:

```
out = tf.Variable(tf.zeros(shape=tf.shape(tf_a1), dtype=tf.float32), validate_shape=False)
```

Then it raises this error:

> ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer repeater: expected
>   ndim=2, found ndim=None

**Update1**

when I try this one:

```
out = tf.Variable(tf.zeros_like(tf_a1, dtype=tf.float32))
```

It raises again the error:

> initial_value must have a shape specified:
>   Tensor("lambda_1/zeros_like:0", shape=(?, 20), dtype=float32)

Also, when I give it explicitly like this:

```
out = tf.Variable(tf.zeros(shape=(BATCH_SIZE, LATENT_SIZE), dtype=tf.float32))
```

It raises this error:

> ValueError: An operation has `None` for gradient. Please make sure
>   that all of your ops have a gradient defined (i.e. are
>   differentiable). Common ops without gradient: K.argmax, K.round,
>   K.eval.

Just in case the model can help to figue out where this error comes from:

this is the lambda layer, in which just change the matrice a little bit:

```
def score_cooccurance(tf_a1):
    N = tf.shape(tf_a1)[0]
    n = 2
    input_tf = tf.concat([tf_a1, tf.zeros((1, tf_a1.shape[1]), tf_a1.dtype)], axis=0)
    tf_a2 = tf.sort(sent_wids, axis=1)
    first_col_change = tf.zeros([tf_a2.shape[0], 1], dtype=tf.int32)
    last_cols_change = tf.cast(tf.equal(tf_a2[:, 1:], tf_a2[:, :-1]), tf.int32)
    change_bool = tf.concat([first_col_change, last_cols_change], axis=-1)
    not_change_bool = 1 - change_bool
    tf_a2_changed = tf_a2 * not_change_bool + change_bool * N #here

    idx = tf.where(tf.count_nonzero(tf.gather(input_tf, tf_a2_changed, axis=0), axis=1) >= n)
    y, x = idx[:, 0], idx[:, 1]
    rows_tf = tf.gather(tf_a2, y, axis=0)

    columns_tf = tf.cast(x[:, None], tf.int32)

    out = tf.Variable(tf.zeros(shape=(BATCH_SIZE, LATENT_SIZE), dtype=tf.float32))

    rows_tf = tf.reshape(rows_tf, shape=[-1, 1])

    columns_tf = tf.reshape(
        tf.tile(columns_tf, multiples=[1, tf.shape(tf_a2)[1]]),
        shape=[-1, 1])

    sparse_indices = tf.reshape(
        tf.concat([rows_tf, columns_tf], axis=-1),
        shape=[-1, 2])
    v = tf.gather_nd(input_tf, sparse_indices)
    v = tf.reshape(v, [-1, tf.shape(tf_a2)[1]])

    scatter = tf.scatter_nd_update(out, tf.cast(sparse_indices, tf.int32), tf.reshape(v, shape=[-1]))
    return scatter
```

Actually when I print out the shape of `out` it print out `<unknown>`.

Any idea or tricks how can I fix this?

I am using `tensorflow 1.13.`

Thanks for your help:)

Comment: What is the result of `tf.shape(tf_a1)`?

Comment: @DanielMöller Thank you so much for following. Actually that one is `unknown`. but the matrice being sent to the layer has this shape `(?, 20)`. Even printing this `tf.shape(tf_a1)[0]`,  will report `unknown`.

Comment: `print(tf_a1.shape)` is `(?, 20)`  and `print(tf.shape(tf_a1))` is `Tensor("lambda_1/Shape:0", shape=(2,), dtype=int32)`. the first one is correct.

Comment: What about https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/zeros_like

Comment: Thanks alot for following:), sorry last night I had to leave college as it was very late:). I had tried this option as well, please have a look on the **updat1**

Comment: Are you using eager mode on?

Comment: Yea, it is on `eager mode`,  I added another thing that I tried in the update1

Comment: The problem with the gradient is certainly "in the entire model". A single line will not explain it. Somewhere in the model, between a weight and the loss output, something is cutting the continuity of the function.

Comment: You can't generate a tensor in eager mode without a value (I suppose). It seems `tf_a1` doesn't have a value, like a placeholder.

Comment: Sorry ignore the previous comment, the eager mode is not on

Comment: My model works and the shape exactly correct when I try with only one hypothetical matrice. Do you have time to have a quick look on the model? I will update the question with the model if you can

Comment: Is this `Variable` supposed to be trainable? If this is true, you must do it in a custom layer, not in a `Lambda` layer. Read about "creating your own keras layers". And keep in mind that if you don't keep the "differentiable connection" with the input of the function, it will have None as gradient.

Comment: Actually not, I don't want it to be trainable. My purpose is to change the matrice in the middle layer and then pass it through the next layer. in this case I think Im fine if I use Lambda layer. please correct me if Im wrong

Comment: @DanielMöller Thank you so much for mentioning the issue of tf.Variable, trainable argument.... So I changed the `scatter_nd` to `tensor_scatter_nd_update` to be applied on the `tf.zeros`. now with these to changes it works:)

Comment: @DanielMöller Can I ask you please have a look at my question here, I just want to know which optimizer is doing better and what could be the reason of sharp decline. I appreciate if you can have a look as it is hard to get my answer in 
 stackexchange.    https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/417535/how-to-interpret-the-sharp-decline-in-loss-in-seq2seq-models

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the workaround in my case was to remove the `tf.variable` an only have `tf.zeros`. 
in this case, the `tf.scater_nd_update` raises error as it can not be applied on the `tensors`.

It seems that there is `tensor_scatter_nd_update` I did not know before. so I changed that line as well, now the code working fine, though I did not get the main reason of the error. I just change it to this way to get it run sucessfully.

```
out = tf.zeros(shape=tf.shape(tf_a1), dtype=tf.float32)
scatter = tf.tensor_scatter_update(out, tf.cast(sparse_indices, tf.int32), tf.reshape(v, shape=[-1]))
```

Thanks to @Daniel Moller for pointing out the concept of trainable variables... :)